# Running a SQL script (Transact-SQL) with a HostedService [ASP.NET CORE 3.1.0 C#]

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run a script that saves my database with a service that I created:

Here is the code of my service:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEST_BACKUP_DB
{    
    internal interface IScopedDBService
    {
        Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }

    public class ScopedDBService : IScopedDBService
    {
            private int executionCount = 0;
            private readonly ILogger _logger;

            public ScopedDBService(ILogger<ScopedDBService> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;

            }

            public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
            {

                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {

                string sqlConnectionString = 
                    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user1\Documents\DB_TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

                string script = File.ReadAllText(@"myscript.sql");

                try {

                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

                    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

                    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

                    executionCount++;

                    _logger.LogInformation(
                        "Saving DB count: {Count}", executionCount);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Error not saved: {e}",e);
                }

                await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

To consume that service I'm using the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static TEST_BACKUP_DB.ScopedDBService;

namespace TEST_BACKUP_DB
{
    public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> _logger;

        public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services,
            ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
        {
            Services = services;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

            await DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }

        private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedProcessingService =
                    scope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<IScopedDBService>();

                await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is stopping.");

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

I have registred them on Startup.cs Class as following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
            services.AddScoped<IScopedDBService, ScopedDBService>();
        }
```

My Transact-SQL(myscript.sql) file is:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DB_TEST]
TO DISK = 'D:\BACKUPS\_1.BAK'
MIRROR TO DISK = 'D:\BACKUPS\_2.BAK'
WITH FORMAT
GO
```

I have tested the scopped service without this part of code, and it's working fine:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

When I start my app it gives me this exception:

[image]

When I debug I get this on the server attribute:

> ActiveDirectory = 'server.ActiveDirectory' threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UnsupportedFeatureException'

I have installed the nugetPackage: `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObject` to use the Server Class, is the problem coming from there? Does anyone have any alternatives or solutions?

Comment: Based on the screenshot, I would guess that SQL LocalDB does not support backup mirroring.

Comment: Okey I tried removing it and it still giving me errors :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need SMO to run a TSQL batch, and the BACKUP/RESTORE errors will all be in the SqlException.Errors collection.  You are only seeing the last one.

EG

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = script;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            throw;
         }
    }
```

will output the root cause, something like:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Database 'xxxxx' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: It gives me this error : `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Database 'DB_TEST' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.` 
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.` then my application stops with an exception unhandled.

Comment: Well, now you know why it's failing.

Comment: but when I debug in the `conn` variable it gives me `ServerVersion = 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`

Comment: You can't evaluate arbitrary properties at a break point.  Properties run code.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.`

Comment: I could just start guessing. You left the `@` off of your connection string liters.

Comment: No my connection string look like this : `string sqlConnectionString = 
                    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\DB_TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";`

Comment: My guess was so close.  Read about escape sequences and verbatim strings here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, now I'm getting the error that says that the DB_TEST doesn't exist :(

Comment: Good, now you know why it's failing again.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot, I had to create a new DATABASE and know it's working just fine :)